# javascript recursion in loop return statement not working

Tags: javascript

I have a loop in which I have a recursive function which does not return and stop. Here is code

```
var obj = {
    here: { is: "an" },
    object: 2
};
var obj1 = {
    here: { is: "aan" },
    object: 2
};
function objectTester(x) {
    if (typeof x === 'object' && x !== null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function deepEqual(valOne, valTwo) {
    debugger
    if (objectTester(valOne) && objectTester(valTwo)) {
        for (key in valOne) {
            if (valTwo.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (objectTester(valOne[key]) && objectTester(valTwo[key])) {
                    deepEqual(valOne[key], valTwo[key]);
                }
                else {
                    if (valOne[key] === valTwo[key]) {
                    }
                    else {

                        return false;       //function dose not stop executing and return false
                    }

                }

            }
            else {

                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    else {

        return false;
    }
}
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj1));
```

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/nmLeutmg/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call deepEqual recursively here:

```
if (objectTester(valOne[key]) && objectTester(valTwo[key])) {
    deepEqual(valOne[key], valTwo[key]);
}
```

you are ignoring the return value from the recursive call so its gonna loop over everything irrespective of the inner objects being equal or not.

Try

```
if(!deepEqual(valOne[key], valTwo[key])){ return false }
```

Another alternative is throwing an exception (and catching it at the top) instead of returning booleans. This makes your control flow jump straight out no matter how many levels of recursion you have.